# Sinatra App JSON and Routes

Tags: ruby, json, activerecord, routes, sinatra

**Scenario**
I have a Sinatra App
I have a route that fetches articles based on a certain named path

```
# Get Articles for a certain time period

get '/frontpage/:type' do  
    case params[:type]

    when "today"
      @news = Article.find(...)
    when "yesterday"
      @news = Article.find(...)
    when "week-ago" 
      @news = Article.find(...)
    when "month-ago" 
      @news = Article.find(...)
      else
        not_found
    end

    erb :frontpage

end
```

**Question**
Is it possible to keep this route `"/frontpage/:type"` and show a .json page if for example someone ask for `"/frontpage/:today.json"` instead of `"/frontpage/:type"` ?

OR

Is it better to create a separate route specifically for requests for JSON ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a new route.

Though, you can factor your code like that:

```
get '/frontpage/:type' do
  @news = get_articles(params[:type])
  erb :frontpage
end

get '/frontpage/:type.json' do
  get_articles(params[:type]).json
end

def get_articles(type)
  case 
  when "today"
    Article.find(...)
  when "yesterday"
    Article.find(...)
  when "week-ago" 
    Article.find(...)
  when "month-ago" 
    Article.find(...)
  else
    raise "Unsupported type #{type}. Supported types are: today, yesterday, week-ago and month-ago."
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a great example. I kept thinking it would be one method. Never considered breaking it up like this.

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be done with a single route:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get %r{/frontpage/([^\.]+)\.?(.+)?} do |type, ext|
  'the type is: ' + type + ' and the extension is: ' + "#{ext}"
end
```

You can the use the ext var to return your json content if it's non-nill, and has the value 'json'.

Answer (score 0):

The [route order](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html) matters.

Compare this app, .json first

```
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/contrib/all"

get "/greet/:name.json" do |name|
  json ({"greeting" => greeting(name)})
end

get "/greet/:name" do |name|
  greeting name
end

def greeting(name)
  "Hello #{name}"
end
```

with this app, .json last

```
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/contrib/all"

get "/greet/:name" do |name|
  greeting name
end

get "/greet/:name.json" do |name|
  json ({"greeting" => greeting(name)})
end

def greeting(name)
  "Hello #{name}"
end
```

With the first:

```
$ curl localhost:4567/greet/frank
Hello frank

$ curl localhost:4567/greet/frank.json
{"greeting": "Hello frank"}
```

But with the second,

```
$ curl localhost:4567/greet/frank
Hello frank

$ curl localhost:4567/greet/frank.json
Hello frank.json
```